# How can I send cookie to the client so that the session_id I am sending will be exclusive for that Web site?

Tags: javascript, authentication, session-cookies

I have this clients like 10.10.210.210/myApp1 and 10.10.210.210/myApp2. These 2 apps call common APIs.I have this login API for these apps like 10.10.210.210/live/login and other APIs as 10.10.210.210./live/xyz.
We are sending `session_id` cookie in the response of login API so that we can use that to authenticate for other APIs, but if I am opening these two client apps together on two different tabs of browser, `session_id` cookie is getting overwritten for them by each other.

I have tried adding few checks in PATH and DOMAIN attribute of cookie header but nothing worked.

Can you please suggest what can I do to distinguish these two `session_id` cookies.